# What is the difference between calling a function with call/apply or directly?

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js, apply

I know that by calling apply you have access to a different this property from within the function, but in this specific situation I have no idea why they would be any different. Wouldn't the 'this' be coming from the same place (item) regardless ?

This original code did not work:

```
_.invoke = function (collection, methodName) {

    var slicedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

    return _.map(collection, (item) => {
        if (typeof methodName === "string") {
            return item[methodName](slicedArgs);
        } else {
            return methodName.apply(item, slicedArgs);
        }
    });
};
```

And when I changed what was inside the map function it worked fine:

```
_.invoke = function (collection, methodName) {
    var slicedArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

    return _.map(collection, (item) => {
        if (typeof methodName === "string") {
            return item[methodName].apply(item, slicedArgs);
        } else {
            return methodName.apply(item, slicedArgs);
        }
    });
};
```

So what's the deal with apply? What was the 'this' binding to in my first code, and what changed in the second?

Comment: The first one is `method([1,2,3])`, and apply spreads the array into each argument position, making it `method(1,2,3)`.

Comment: wow, I can't believe that took me so long. Thank you for that Andy, You saved my brain from exploding!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you were missing the `...` to spread your `slicedArgs` array into several arguments, so you passed the array itself as a single argument. If you change your code to `return item[methodName](...slicedArgs)` it will work.

The reason it works with `apply` is that `apply` takes an *array* of arguments.

Comment: Thanks CherryDT! I have never really used call, apply or bind much until this point, and so I had completely forgotten that i would need to spread the args.